# how to use "Cloud TPU" in google compute engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I activated the API to use the Cloud TPU menu. And I tried to create the node but it failed. What's wrong with the pop-ups without content?

What do I have to do to use Cloud TPU?

thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you have [quota for TPUs](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/tpu.googleapis.com/quotas?_ga=2.82886036.-369476931.1515684380&_gac=1.213583520.1516200277.EAIaIQobChMIuICXh57f2AIVhhbTCh0T1wsxEAAYASAAEgIpX_D_BwE)? Follow the instructions in the [documentation quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart#before-you-begin) in order to check that you have everything that is required.

Comment: Also, if you go to the [Activity page in the Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/activity), you will be able to see an error regarding the failed creation of a Cloud TPU. I have tried this myself, and it shows the error `Resource exhausted (HTTP 429): Quota for 'node-1' has been exhausted`, as I have not requested quota for TPUs yet. Hope that helps.

Comment: @dsesto The quota was a matter of course, but I missed it. thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

As @dsesto says in the comments above, the "Before You Begin" section of the Cloud TPU Quickstart will walk you through everything you need to set up:

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart